# TSQL group-by calculation

Tags: sql-server, math, group-by

I got this table with some data:

```
SELECT Id, SubId, N1, N2, N3 FROM table1 WHERE Id = 2

Id          SubId    N1          N2          N3
----------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------
2           1        94917       97030       0
2           2        35087       41306       0
2           3        189671      194224      0
2           4        44905       46218       0
2           5        65760       70959       0
2           6        620         2395        0
2           7        60336       69531       0
2           8        65517       70666       0
```

I run this query

```
UPDATE table1
SET N3 = CASE WHEN N1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (( N2 * 1.0 / N1 ) -1) * 100 END

Id          SubId    N1          N2          N3
----------- -------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------
2           1        94917       97030       2.2261554832
2           2        35087       41306       17.7245133525
2           3        189671      194224      2.4004723969
2           4        44905       46218       2.9239505622
2           5        65760       70959       7.9060218978
2           6        620         2395        286.2903225806
2           7        60336       69531       15.2396579156
2           8        65517       70666       7.8590289543
```

So, when I group the table by Id i got this data:

```
SELECT  Id, 
        SUM(N1) AS N1, 
        SUM(N2) AS N2, 
        CAST(0 AS NUMERIC(10,2)) AS N3
INTO table2
FROM table1
GROUP BY Id

UPDATE table2
SET N3 = CASE WHEN N1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (( N2 * 1.0 / N1 ) -1) * 100 END

SELECT Id, N1, N2, N3 FROM table2 WHERE Id = 2

Id          N1          N2          N3
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------
2           556813      592329      6.38
```

The question is how I can get the same value of N3 when I group by ID (6.38) without recalculating the field (second update), I was trying to apply a reverse calculation ((N3/100) + 1) and SUM the N3 field but did not work.

Comment: [offtopic]Shouldn't `FROM table 2` be `FROM table2` ?[/offtopic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `N1` and `N2` with `SUM(N1)` and `SUM(N2)` respectively..

```
SELECT  Id, 
        SUM(N1) AS N1, 
        SUM(N2) AS N2, 
        N3 = CAST(CASE WHEN SUM(N1) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (( SUM(N2) * 1.0 / SUM(N1) ) -1) * 100 END AS NUMERIC(10,2))
FROM table1
GROUP BY Id
```

**Demo at** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/de849/4/0

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Id,
        SUM(N1) AS N1,
        SUM(N2) AS N2,
        CAST(CASE WHEN SUM(N1) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (( SUM(N2) * 1.0 / SUM(N1) ) -1) * 100 END AS NUMERIC(10,2))) as N3
FROM temp
GROUP BY Id
```

N3 needs to have Sum(N1) and Sum(N2) as values instead of N1 and N2 since you are calculating N3 based on aggregates and not individual values.